# Netcat with device or interface flag?

Tags: netcat

Traceroute has an `-i` flag,

> `-i` interface, `--interface=interface` Specifies the interface through which traceroute should send packets. By default, the interface is selected according to the routing table.

`ping` also provides this with `-I`. Netcat has no such flag. Is there an easy work around for `nc`?

Comment: Are you looking for `-s`?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk I don't even think that's ideal, what if two interfaces are assigned the same address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good workaround for *netcat*: [`socat`](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/). This tool can do anything *netcat* can do, and much much more.

On Linux `socat` provides the `so-bindtodevice=` option matching the `SO_BINDTODEVICE` socket option.

Example, to listen on tcp port 4444 binding to interface *veth0* (to force OS to use routes related to this interface), with other options similar to using (OpenBSD variant) `nc -k -l -p 4444`:

```
socat tcp4-listen:4444,so-bindtodevice=veth0,reuseaddr,fork -
```

Which can be checked for example like this:

```
$ ss -tln sport == 4444
State    Recv-Q   Send-Q     Local Address:Port      Peer Address:Port   
LISTEN   0        5          0.0.0.0%veth0:4444           0.0.0.0:*
```

One can also bind as client if that's the need, or even bind differently to the left side socket and the right side socket if using two sockets as parameters.

---

If one knows of an other equivalent socket option on an other *NIX-like OS that would implement the same feature, and `socat` doesn't explicitly implement it, one can still use the generic `setsockopt` and `setsockopt-listen` options to activate it (after retrieving adequate constants from adequate include files).